# getting info from xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

this might be a simple question from a beginner so thanks for your understanding.

With a php script I managed to get some info from my database.  That's the info from a checkup of the variable which holds the data:

```
XMLHttpRequest {statusText: "OK", status: 200, response: "[{"id":"3","login":"ada",...."phone":"123456789"}]", responseType: "", responseXML: null…}
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: function (){
ontimeout: null
readyState: 4
response: "[{"id":"3","login":"ada","created":"2014-06-20 07:00:20","email":"f@o.pl","phone":"123456789"}]"
responseText: "[{"id":"3","login":"ada","created":"2014-06-20 07:00:20","email":"f@o.pl","phone":"123456789"}]"
responseType: ""
responseXML: null
...etc...
```

My question is how do I get to the data Im interested in? I tried `$data.responseText` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: and how are you calling this?

Comment: @epascarello I am not sure what you mean, I tried $data.responseText

Comment: Perhaps I'll add that when I call `$data.responseText` it just returns empty string instead of the data

Comment: Show the actual code, not the output of the console...